# order of a equals 2 but o(e)= 1 why?

Tags: group-theory

let G be any group.and let 'a' belongs to G .a is not equal to e.
and let 'a' is a self inverse element .
since identity(e) is also a self inverse element ,
but o(a)=2 ,& o(e)=1 ,why?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean "$2$ but $o(e)=1$" in the title to agree with the body?  Do you know the definition of order of a group element?

Comment: $a$ is self-inverse$\implies a^2=e\implies1\le o(a)\le2$. In other words, to conclude $o(a)=2$, you would have to assume $a$ is non-identity.

Comment: Order is the smallest positive power to get $a^k = e$.  And $e^1 = 0$.  So the order is $1$.  Being a self inverting element isn't the strongest condition.    Being the identity itself is even stronger.  This is similar to being self inverting being strong then having an order of $4$.  If $b,b^2,b^3,b^4$ are different values and $b^4=e$ the $o(b) =4$.  But if $a$ is self-inverting then $a^4 =1$ also.  But we don't so $o(a)=4$ because $a^2$ is a stronger condition.

Comment: Or...... being "self-inverting" means $a^2 =e$ but it *doesn't* mean $o(a) = 2$.  $o(a)=2$ means $a^2=e$ *AND* $a\ne e$.  Likewise $a^6=e$ does *not* mean $o(a)=6$. $o(a)=6$ means $a^6=e$ *AND* $a\ne e;a^2\ne e; a^3\ne e; a^4\ne e; a^5\ne e$.  If $a^6=e$ we *could* have $a=e$ or $a^2 =e$ or $a^3 = e$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $a^k=e$ only implies that $o(a)|k\in\Bbb N$. Thus you have $o(a)|2$, meaning $o(a)$ could be $1$ or $2$. In case $a=e,o(a)=1$. Otherwise $o(a)=2$.

Comment: The OP would do well to note that if $a^2 =e$ then $a^6 = e$.  But we do not say $o(a) =6$.

Comment: @fleablood I said $o(a)|k$

Comment: Right.  But the OP might not think to apply that and notice that $a^6 = e$ as well.

Answer (score 4):

$o(x)$ is the mimimum number of times we need to multiply $x$ by itself to get to $e$. For example $o(x) = n$ means $\underbrace{x\cdot x \dots x}_{n\text{ times}}=e$. For your $a$, assuming $a\neq e$, $n$ is two since $\underbrace{a\cdot a}_{2\text{ times}} = e$ and one for $e$ since $\underbrace{e}_{1\text{ time}} = e$.

Comment: How did you conclude $n=2$?

Comment: assuming $a\ne e$

Comment: @stochastic That assumption needs to be stated. And the definition of order doesn't seem right.

Comment: Ok . If o(a)=1 then a^1 =e .i.e.a=e but 'a' does not equal to e

Answer (score 0):

Order is the *smallest* positive power to get $a^k = e$.  And $e^1 = e$.  So the order is $1$.

$o(a) = k$ does not *just* mean that $a^k= e$.  It *also* means that for all $i: 1\le i < k$ that $a^k\ne e$.  After all if $a^k = e$ then $a^{mk} =(a^k)^m =e^m = e$ as well.  But only *one* value can be the order.  And that is the smallest.

If $a \ne e$ and $a^2 = e$ then $o(a) = 2$.  But if $a^2 = e$ *and* $a^1=e$ then $o(a) = 1$.  But the only time we have $a^1=e$ is when $a^1=a = e$.  $e$ is the only element with order $1$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to define the order of an element is as the order of the cyclic subgroup generated by that element, and since $\langle e \rangle = \{e\}$, $o(e) = 1$.